# Prove that similarity function over sets satisfies triangle inequality

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The following setting has been troubling me for a while:

Let $A,B,C$ be three unordered sets of integers
and
$sim(A,B) = \cfrac{|A\cap B|}{max({|A|,|B|})}, max(|A|,|B|)\neq0$

The goal is to prove or disprove that $sim(\cdot,\cdot)$ satisfies the triangle inequality.

> $sim(A,C) \leq sim(A,B)+sim(B,C)$ for any triplet $(A,B,C)$

Any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks,
Nikos

Comment: actually i'm pretty sure that $\frac12<1+1$

Comment: that is a fair observation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A\cap B=\emptyset$, $B\cap C=\emptyset$, $A\cap C\ne \emptyset$, then
$$
0=\text{sim}(A,B)+\text{sim}(B,C)<\text{sim}(A,C)
$$
Hence, the triangle inequality is false.

Comment: +1. In particular if $A,B$ are finite & disjoint & non-empty  and if $C=A$.